# PHP difference between mcrypt and openssl?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, mcrypt

Why have these two methods of using blowfish in ecb-mode different outputs?

```
<?php

echo bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt("blowfish", "test", "test", "ecb"))."\n";
echo bin2hex(openssl_encrypt("test", "bf-ecb", "test", true))."\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of different password-to-encryption-key derivation methods.