# Linux Openssl command to encrypt file that will be decrypted through PHP

Tags: php, openssl, mcrypt

I have to encrypt files that will be decrypted on demand with PHP :

```
$fh = fopen('encrypted_file', 'rb');
$content = fread($fh, $size);
print mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, 'myPassword', $content, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
fclose($fh);
```

I cannot change the PHP code as it is used many times in the site.
Otherwise, I have to seriously prove that the change is mandatory.

Now, my problem is to find the Linux OpenSSL command to encrypt files that will be decrypted with the given code.
I tried things like :

```
openssl enc -e -des3 -k myPassword -nosalt -in text_file -out encrypted_file
```

But I cannot find the decrypted file through PHP.

May you help me to correct the openssl command?
There are so many options (I tried many, I sware) and I don't find how to make them corresponding to the PHP one.

Regards,

Olivier

Comment: Probably this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581677/php-difference-between-mcrypt-and-openssl

Comment: I already noticed that the password may be encrypted in different ways and I tried to encrypt the file with bin2hex('myPassword') but it didn't give any relevant result.
Thanks anyway for your answer